# Trouble running loop with variable

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am writing a script to pull a list of users and then archive that list of users mailboxes and archives into psts

```
$Lines = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmailAddress
$Lines | select EmailAddress | Where {$_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | Out-File "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"

(Get-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt") | ForEach { $_.Trim() } | Set-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"

$Names = Get-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"
$Emails = $Names.Split("@")[0]
Add-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.Exchange, Microsoft.Windows.AD

$SubPath1 = "\\qnap1\archive\exchange_Migration\"
$SubPath2 = "_Primary_mailbox.pst"
$SubPath3 = "_Archive_mailbox.pst"

ForEach ($Email in $Emails) { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email -FilePath "$Subpath1 + $Email.Split("@")[0] + $SubPath2" ; New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email.Split("@")[0] -FilePath "$Subpath1 + $Email + $SubPath3" -IsArchive }
```

Where I am strugglng is getting the variables correct. I want to use the full e-mail address with the export request command but only the name part of the email (not domain) in the path for the export

Comment: Change `"$Subpath1 + $Email.Split("@")[0] + $SubPath2"` to `($Subpath1 + $Email.Split("@")[0] + $SubPath2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few things going on.  When you are unrolling the `.Split("@")` on the `$Names` array you are then indexing into it with `[0]`. That's going to return the first element of the array that resulted from the split. NOT the first element resulting from each split...

But there's not a need for that anyhow.  You could simply a few ways, one example:

```
Add-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.Exchange, Microsoft.Windows.AD

$Lines = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '*'" -Properties EmailAddress
$Lines | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress | 
Out-File "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"

(Get-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt").Trim() | 
Set-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"

$Emails = Get-Content "C:\T2\EMailAddresses.txt"

$SubPath1 = "\\qnap1\archive\exchange_Migration\"
$SubPath2 = "_Primary_mailbox.pst"
$SubPath3 = "_Archive_mailbox.pst"

ForEach ($Email in $Emails)
{
    $Alias = $Email.Split("@")[0]
    $FilePathPrimary = "$Subpath1" + $Alias + $SubPath2
    $FilePathArchive = "$Subpath1" + $Alias + $SubPath3

    New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email -FilePath $FilePathPrimary
    New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email -FilePath $FilePathArchive -IsArchive 
}
```

Note: I obviously can't test this.

You can use emails directly, then simply calculate the arguments for your export commands on each loop iteration.  This comes out cleaner and easier to read.

Also Notice:

1. Use of `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` this will return just the email addresses for the file.
2. Unrolling the `.Trim()` method on the results of `Get-Content` instead of running it through a `ForEach-Object` loop.
3. Moving filter criteria left in the command/pipeline by leveraging the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ADUser`, which is a performance best practice. Especially when commands have their own and/or adequate filtering capabilities to do so.

**An Aside:**

There are a few other things that can be done to simplify.  However, the way this is presented thus far, there's actually no need to intermediate the data with files.  So I'm going to skip making enhancements in that area.  Instead you could take the output from `Get-ADUser` and use it directly.  Again, lot's of ways to do it, but building off what we already have, here's one example:

```
Add-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.Exchange, Microsoft.Windows.AD

$SubPath1 = "\\qnap1\archive\exchange_Migration\"
$SubPath2 = "_Primary_mailbox.pst"
$SubPath3 = "_Archive_mailbox.pst"

$Emails = (Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '*'" -Properties EmailAddress).EMailAddresses

ForEach($Email in $Emails)
{
    $Alias = $Email.Split("@")[0]
    $FilePathPrimary = "$Subpath1" + $Alias + $SubPath2
    $FilePathArchive = "$Subpath1" + $Alias + $SubPath3

    New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email -FilePath $FilePathPrimary
    New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Email -FilePath $FilePathArchive -IsArchive
}
```

**Warning:**

Beyond the scope of the question, but all the code so far assumes the mailbox indeed has an enabled archive.  If or when that is not the case the attempt to export the archive will likely throw up a bloody red error.  You can handle that by introducing some error handling. Or, you might consider rewriting by using `Get-Mailbox` from the Exchange tools instead of `Get-ADUser`